# Sending Text from arduino to arduino

Tags: arduino, keyboard

I try to make a simple arduino computer,using the keyboard and TVout library.
Because the Librarys are incompatible , I want to use the arduino mega as mainboard, and a arduino uno as a graphic chip.
But IT always shows only numbers on the TV.

My question: How can you send text between two arduinos via Serial

Mainboard(Mega with keyboard) code

```
#include <PS2Keyboard.h>PS2Keyboard.h
const int DataPin = 8;
const int IRQpin =  5;

PS2Keyboard keyboard;

void setup() {
  //keyboard.begin(DataPin, IRQpin, PS2Keymap_US);
  keyboard.begin(DataPin, IRQpin, PS2Keymap_German);
  //keyboard.begin(DataPin, IRQpin, PS2Keymap_French);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("International Keyboard Test:");
}

void loop() {
  if (keyboard.available()) {
    char c = keyboard.read();
    Serial.println(c);
  }
}
```

Video board code(TVout)

```
#include <TVout.h>TVout.h
#include <fontALL.h>fontALL.h
TVout TV;

void setup() {
  TV.begin(PAL,120,96);
  TV.select_font(font6x8);
  TV.println("Videochip OK");

  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
  TV.print(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I don't have all the required circuitry to test this for myself I can only guide.

1. Change the keyboard arduino sketch (top) to use `Serial.write`instead of `println`, `println` can do some conversion and will append a newline character at the end.
2. Try storing the input of the keyboard to a byte, not a char as the you are storing a keycode.
3. Change `if(Serial.available())` to `while (Serial.available())` and the same for keyboard.
4. Try constructing at char[] (string) out of all available characters in the serial port on the graphics arduino then send this to `TV.print(text)`. Although `print` accepts bytes, chars and strings, those methods may not do all the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, but the video board stil outputs numbers,

Comment: how do you make a char?

Answer (score 0):

You  should change the video board code first store `Serial.read()` to some character data type, *then* use the print function. I also faced the same problem with Bluetooth communication programme.